# What's the difference between the AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_32_BIT and AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, audio, pcm

The AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_32_BIT and AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT are two high definition audio formats in Android Lollipop.

Seems they are all in 32 bit depth.

Who know the exactly difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

You can find that information in [audio.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/include/system/audio.h):

```
/* Audio format consists of a main format field (upper 8 bits) and a sub
   format field (lower 24 bits).
```

`AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_32_BIT` and `AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT` are defined as:

```
AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_32_BIT          = (AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM |
                                    AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_SUB_32_BIT),
AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT        = (AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM |
                                    AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_SUB_8_24_BIT),
```

And if we look at the definitions of `AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_SUB_32_BIT` and `AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT` we find some helpful comments:

```
AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_SUB_32_BIT          = 0x3, /* PCM signed .31 fixed point */
AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_SUB_8_24_BIT        = 0x4, /* PCM signed 7.24 fixed point */
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the difference between .31 fixed point and 7.24 fixed point?

Comment: `signed .31` means 1 bit for sign, 0 bits for the whole part, and 31 bits for the fractional part. `signed 7.24` means 1 bit for sign, 7 bits for the whole part, and 24 bits for the fractional part. Read up on fixed-point arithmetic if you want to know more about how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

In response to [Michael's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082952/whats-the-difference-between-the-audio-format-pcm-32-bit-and-audio-format-pcm-8#comment44550129_28084032):

> `signed .31` means 1 bit for sign, 0 bits for the whole part, and 31 bits for the fractional part. `signed 7.24` means 1 bit for sign, 7 bits for the whole part, and 24 bits for the fractional part. Read up on fixed-point arithmetic if you want to know more about how it's used.

`AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT` most likely refers to a padded 8 bits of zeros as the 7.24 fixed point doesn't make sense for PCM data. This is because PCM data ranges from [1.0 .. -1.0]. (it technically should be 8.23, otherwise 7.24 == 25-bits!). So the use of a "whole" [number] part does not make sense.

A single sample of `AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_8_24_BIT` will contain 4 bytes, where only 3 bytes will hold any meaningful data and the remaining single byte will be all zeros.

The alternative is `AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_24_BIT_PACKED` that only contains 3 bytes per sample and *no* padding. 24-bit audio has a strange format, and it doesn't fit well in the powers of 2 of digital audio. It is typically easier to handle a 24-bit sample as if it was 32-bit.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/audio/data_formats